# Next JS First Contentful Paint(FCP) time optimisation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, lighthouse

I am working on next js based react app and I am trying to minimize the First Contentful Paint(FCP) time, I have tried dynamic imports wherever possible, moved images to CDN but it didn't help. is there any other way to improve the FCP score for my site page. I have nothing to share as a code or what I have done so far. please anyone suggest how can I improve the FCP score.

Comment: I am also using next/images for image display......

Comment: You should pinpoint the cause for the low FCP score. I'd recommend a read through https://web.dev/fcp/#how-to-improve-fcp.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do many things :

**1-** Using `Next js` build in `<Image/>` component

**2-** Minimizing your `css` files with `PurgeCss`

**3-** Using `SSG` and `ISR` rendering techniques

**4-** Use `@Next/bundle-analyzer` to analyze your `js` bundles

and so on .....